# SimpleCV installation on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, pip

I want to install [SimpleCV](http://simplecv.org), a Python framework for computer vision, on my Raspberry Pi.

These are the steps I followed:

- Step 1 - install dependencies

  - `sudo apt-get install python-opencv python-scipy python-numpy python-pip`
- Step 2 - install SimpleCV from `pip`

  - `sudo pip install https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/zipball/master`

I got these steps from a Raspberry Pi tutorial, "Getting started with Raspberry Pi"
by Matt Richardson and Shawn Wallace. However, the installation did not succeed.

Is there any other way to install simple CV on raspberry pi?

Answer (score 4):

To automatically install the dependencies, use the -f prefix.

Try the code below.

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get -f install python-opencv python-scipy python-numpy python-pip 
sudo pip install https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/zipball/master
```

**EDIT**

I didn't test the code earlier but here is what I found.

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get -f install python-opencv python-scipy python-numpy python-pip
```

This worked perfectly fine and installed all the dependencies.However the third line failed miserably.
The problem is pip puts the temporary files on RAM and the large SimpleCV failed.

So I followed the following  lines and it installed the SimpleCV.

```
wget https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/master    
sudo pip install file:///home/pi/master --download-cache /home/pi/tmp
```

This worked and the SimpleCV worked nicely.

To open the SimpleCV interactive shell, type

```
simplecv
```

on the terminal.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Stevelrwin Thank you for your answer. but it was not working.. anyway, thank you for your answer.. :) i formatted my SD card in raspberry pi. and then followed the same steps. (pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install python-opencv python-scipy pythonnumpy
python-pip and pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo pip install https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/
zipball/master  ) all i had done it in the root (sudo su).. it was found working.. but the problem is that SimpleCV folder was not there in the file manager on raspberry pi.. how will i locate SimpleCV folder and SimpleCV shell??

Comment: What is the difference between  sudo apt-get install python-opencv python-scipy python-numpy python-pip 
and sudo apt-get install ipython python-opencv python-scipy python-numpy python-pip that is ipython and python ????

Comment: @AjithaThrakan I edited my answer.Check it.

Comment: SimpleCV repo has moved: https://github.com/sightmachine/simplecv