# Unable to install SimpleCV on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, software-installation, pi-3, modules, pip

I've tried multiple times and different ways to install SimpleCV for Python2 on my Raspberry Pi 3. I was able to do this with no problem on RP2.

The first method I tried was using pip:
`sudo pip install https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/zipball/master`
This ended up with the following error:

```
ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ingenuitas/SimpleCV/zipball/master (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x76176d30>, 'Connection to github.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)'))
```

This doesn't make sense because I can ping the site and I'm definitely connected to the internet.

So I moved on and tried to install it using source:

```
mkdir ~/Code
cd ~/Code
git clone git://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV.git
cd SimpleCV
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
sudo python setup.py develop
```

However after installation when i try to run it i get an error about Scipy:

`ImportError: No module named scipy.ndimage`

So then I tried installing Scipy, which literally said it could not find any files associated with Scipy.

I'm pretty much exhausted of ideas here, I don't understand why none of this isn't working, whether a module changed or if there is something wrong with my Pi. How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Did you checked http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6806/simplecv-installation-on-raspberry-pi?rq=1 ?

Comment: @ahmetertem Yes that is one of the first threads I tried, similar issue as the first method i listed in the post.

Answer (score 2):

I succeed running SimpleCV on RPi3 without updating os from RPi2.
I just installed like following steps.

```
mkdir ~/Code
cd ~/Code
git clone git://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV.git
cd SimpleCV
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
sudo pip install svgwrite
sudo python setup.py develop
```

Answer (score -3):

You must update os using RPi2,then take SD Card to Rpi3. It's work.

Comment: Why would this work? What is the basis for this? As the OP makes no mention of RPi2 other than installing it worked on a Pi2, Why would he have to have a Pi2 to install.