# SimpleCV is not downloading!

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, camera, software-installation, computer-vision

Whenever I try to install SimpleCV, I always get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>

    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead
```

What went wrong and can you give me the code to install SimpleCV properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install SimpleCV, first install the prerequisite packages using these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ipython python-opencv python-scipy 
$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-setuptools python-pip
$ sudo pip install svgwrite
```

Then install SimpleCV itself using the command:

```
$ sudo pip install https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV/zipball/master
```

If this command not working you can alternatively use this:

```
$sudo pip install https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/zipball/master
```

Once installation is complete, you can check that everything worked by running this
command(You can also check is simpleCV installed on your Pi before using this command):

```
$ simplecv
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
 SimpleCV 1.3.0 [interactive shell] - http://simplecv.org
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
Commands: 
 "exit()" or press "Ctrl+ D" to exit the shell
 "clear()" to clear the shell screen
 "tutorial()" to begin the SimpleCV interactive tutorial
 "example()" gives a list of examples you can run
 "forums()" will launch a web browser for the help forums
 "walkthrough()" will launch a web browser with a walkthrough
```

This will open the SimpleCV console. This is a Python console, with extra features for
SimpleCV. However [installation of simpleCV already asked](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6806/simplecv-installation-on-raspberry-pi) on Stack Exchange. This may also helpful for you. If you are installed OpenCV before that may be a reason for failure of simpleCV installation. [Alternate method for installing simpleCV](http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/install/simplecv-on-rpi.html) is discussed on this article. But I didn't used this method yet. Since first method was worked for me.

Comment: I just tried "sudo pip install svgwrite" and it gave me a long traceback error

Comment: @AdityaMangalampalli Do you entered the 3 commands before sudo pip install svgwrite? Do you Installed openCV before? Please add more information in question...